# How to improve the speed of reading a large file line by line in Go

Tags: performance, go

I'm trying to figure out the fastest way of reading a large file line by line and checking if the line contains a string. The file I'm testing on is about 680mb in size:

```golang
    package main
    
    import (
        "bufio"
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "strings"
    )
    
    func main() {
        f, err := os.Open("./crackstation-human-only.txt")
    
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer f.Close()
    
        for scanner.Scan() {
            if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), "Iforgotmypassword") {
                fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
            }
        }
    }
```

After building the program and timing it on my machine it runs over 3 seconds
`./speed  3.13s user 1.25s system 122% cpu 3.563 total`

After increasing the buffer

```
buf := make([]byte, 64*1024)
scanner.Buffer(buf, bufio.MaxScanTokenSize)
```

It gets a little better
`./speed  2.47s user 0.25s system 104% cpu 2.609 total`

I know it can get better because other tools manage to do it under a second without any kind of indexing. What seems to be the bottleneck with this approach?

`0.33s user 0.14s system 94% cpu 0.501 total`

Comment: `scanner.Text` requires a string conversion, so using `scanner.Bytes` instead and `bytes.Contains` instead of `string.Contains` might be faster. `fmt.Println` is also not the fastest, and as written involves doing the string conversion a second time. But generally speaking you should profile the code to find where you're losing speed.

Comment: removing the string conversions also doesn't help. if I have only a line counter
`counter := 0

 for scanner.Scan() {
  counter++
 } `
it doesn't get faster, only a little bit. So it seems that the bootle neck is scanner.Scan() but don't know how to improve this.

Comment: Have you tried setting a larger buffer? There's also no timing information in the code here, how are you running your program?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you timing a built executable or are you timing `go run`?

Comment: time ./programname which gives `./programname  2.53s user 0.49s system 99% cpu 3.025 total`

Comment: I have edited my answer to give a short run-time program that will match entire lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**LAST EDIT**

This is a "line-by-line" solution to the problem that takes trivial time, it prints the entire matching line.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    dat, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./jumble.txt")
    i := bytes.Index(dat, []byte("Iforgotmypassword"))
    if i != -1 {
        var x int
        var y int
        for x = i; x > 0; x-- {
            if dat[x] == byte('\n') {
                break
            }
        }
        for y = i; y < len(dat); y++ {
            if dat[y] == byte('\n') {
                break
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(string(dat[x : y+1]))
    }
}
```

```
real    0m0.421s
user    0m0.068s
sys     0m0.352s
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you just need to see if the string is in a file, why not use regex?

Note: I kept the data as a byte array instead of converting to string.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "regexp"
)

var regex = regexp.MustCompile(`Ilostmypassword`)

func main() {
    dat, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./jumble.txt")
    if regex.Match(dat) {
        fmt.Println("Yes")
    }
}
```

`jumble.txt` is a 859 MB of jumbled text with newlines included.

Running with `time ./code` I get:

```
real    0m0.405s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.340s
```

<strike>To try and answer your comment, I don't think the bottleneck is inherently coming from searching line by line, Golang uses an efficient algorithm for searching strings/runes.</strike>

I think the bottleneck comes from the IO reads, when the program reads from the file, it is normally not first in line in the queue of reading, therefore, the program must wait until it can read in order to start actually comparing.  Thus, when you are reading in over and over, you are being forced to wait for your turn in IO.

To give you some math, if your buffer size is 64 * 1024 (or 65535 bytes), and your file is 1 GB.  Dividing 1 GB / 65535 bytes is 15249 reads needed to check the entire file.  Where as in my method, I read the entire file "at once" and check against that constructed array.

Another thing I can think of is just the utter amount of loops needed to move through the file and the time needed for each loop:

Given the following code:

```
dat, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./jumble.txt")
sdat := bytes.Split(dat, []byte{'\n'})
for _, l := range sdat {
    if bytes.Equal([]byte("Iforgotmypassword"), l) {
        fmt.Println("Yes")
    }
}
```

I calculated that each loop takes on average 32 nanoseconds, the string Iforgotmypassword was on line 100000000 in my file, thus the execution time for this loop was roughly 32 nanoseconds * 100000000 ~= 3.2 seconds.

Comment: This really does speed it up `./speed  0.35s user 0.49s system 99% cpu 0.845 total` a lot, but what I'm trying to understand is where is the bootle neck when going line by line

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer. Following this logic increasing the buffer to 1GB would make it equally fast, since everything would be in memory, but this doesn’t seem to be the case. It still runs slower

Answer (score 1):

Using my own 700MB test file with your original, time was just over 7 seconds

With grep it was 0.49 seconds

With this program (which doesn't print out the line, it just says yes)
0.082 seconds

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
func main() {
    find := []byte(os.Args[1])
    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("crackstation-human-only.txt")
    check(err)
    if bytes.Contains(dat, find) {
        fmt.Print("yes")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed fast and works, but I still don't understand why the line by line solution fails

Comment: A line-by-line solution needs to check each byte once to see if it's a newline, break those bytes into chunks based on where the newlines are, and then check those chunks again against the string you're looking for. Since you'll consider any line to match if it _contains_ the string you want, it's fine to just iterate once through the file, treating the whole thing like one big byte sequence.

Answer (score 1):

H. Ross' answer is awesome, but it reads the whole file into memory, which may not be feasible if your file is too big.  If you still want to scan line-by-line, perhaps if you're searching for multiple items, I found that using scanner.Bytes() instead of scanner.Text() improves speed slightly on my machine, from 2.244s for the original question, to 1.608s.  bufio's scanner.Bytes() method doesn't allocate any additional memory, whereas Text() creates a string from its buffer.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "bytes"
)

// uses scanner.Bytes to avoid allocation.
func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("./crackstation-human-only.txt")

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    toFind := []byte("Iforgotmypassword")

    for scanner.Scan() {
        if bytes.Contains(scanner.Bytes(), toFind) {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
    }
}
```